# make image fill up and centered within slider

Tags: html, css

I've tried many methods (probably all wrong) to center the image within the slider and make it fill up the tile proportionately, but still fail.

What I want is for the image to be:

```
min-width:100%;
width:auto;
min-height:100%;
height:auto;
vertically and horizontally centered
```

I tried using

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

but it didn't work.

Would be great if I could get some guidance here.

staging url:
http://multisite.thesuit.sg/tatwai-r1/portfolio-item/uob-268/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```html
< div style=”width:300px;height:300px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;line-height:300px;border:1px solid #ccc;display:table-cell”>
　　< img src=”aaaa.jpg” mce_src=”aaaa.jpg” style=”_margin-top: expression_r(( 300 - this.height ) / 2);” />
< /div >
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.